# Microsoft Teams call and chat button

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm quite new to bot framework, we are working on a MS teams app in which i'm using a adaptive card. On that card i'm having buttons for MS teams call and chat. So how to implement a call and chat button for a dynamic users selected from message extension list.

I'm completely new to bot framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Chat** - Please take a look at [Deeplink to chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat) documentation. Use openURL action and specify the URL in value field.
2. **Calling** - Currently, there is no Deeplink to initiate a call. Option would be use [Calls and online meetings bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview).

Comment: Has deeplink to call been created yet?